# Bind multiple Sockets (socket.io) to a single Vuex store with VueSocketio

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, vuejs2, vuex

```
Vue.use(VueSocketio, io(// socket 1), store);
Vue.use(VueSocketio, io(// socket 2), store);
```

I need to bind two different sockets to a single store, is this possible with VueSocketio?